Error in gns3 when start vmware machine Internal server error http://localhost:3080/v2/compute/projects
Error when turn on vmware machine. It work fine before but after I choose configure to add vmnet in Vmware preferences, the error appear. And I think the process of adding the vmnet has error too. I don't know if that is the reason.
Here is the message, w10_tinan is the name of the vmware machine:
error while starting w10_tinan-1: Internal server error http://localhost:3080/v2/compute/projects/5feb7f03-7899-44f6-a516-3ff57db05c10/vmware/nodes/ed6774be-d034-4d08-92d7-9e41dd7bddc2/start
Internal server error http://localhost:3080/v2/compute/projects/5feb7f03-7899-44f6-a516-3ff57db05c10/vmware/nodes/ed6774be-d034-4d08-92d7-9e41dd7bddc2/start
Update: now I can't open the project itself
Error message in the image
